# Regex failed to match filenames

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I am trying to use regex to match the filenames of all files in a folder and extract the suffices.  However, for some reason, the regex seems not to match any file in the folder although files with such pattern exist.

```
check() {
    x=$1
    regex="\/tmp\/a\/b\/c\.${x}\.(.+?)"
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
            if [[ "$file" =~ $regex ]]; then
                # do something
            fi
    done < <(find /tmp/a/b -type f -name "c.${x}.*" -print0)
}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Clarification #1: using `find` isn't a requirement.

Clarification #2: `$x` doesn't have any special character besides underscore.

Clarification #3: `(.+?)` was used because I was trying to extract it and use it later via `$BASH_REMATCH[1]`

My folder:

```
$ ll /tmp/a/b/
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hc hc 0 Jun 20 15:40 list
```

Comment: You seem to want to use a Perl-compatible regular expression, `.+?` (non-greedy `.+`). This is probably not supported by `bash` (AFAIK, it only support extended regular expressions).  Also, it's unclear what `$x` is when you run this code and what the input data looks like, and what happens when you run it.  Why do you escape the `/` characters?  It would be easier and more efficient to incorporate the test on the pathname in the call to `find` with `-path "/tmp/a/b/c.$x.*"` or something similar and then to execute whatever it is you want to do with `-exec`.

Comment: In fact, you should be able to get by by just adding `-maxdepth 1` to the `find` invocations. As you already restrict the names with `-name`, you are then guaranteed to only get files from the `/tmp/a/b` directory, which is what I suppose you're after.

Comment: on a side note why use `while do done < <( find ..)` over `find .. | while do done` ?

Comment: On a side note why use `find` at all? `for f in /tmp/a/b/c.${x}.*; do [[ -f $f ]] && echo ${f##*.} ; done`

Comment: for i in $(find /a/b/c/* -iname '*'); do someCommand "$i"; done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you wanted to check a particular directory rather than a tree of directories, but the RE you provided in your question does not support this requirement.

In this case you can probably dispense with `find` entirely. Here, the glob pattern is mostly equivalent to the RE `^/tmp/a/b/c\.$x\.([^/]+?)$` (with the exception of any RE special characters in `$x`), but this isn't quite the same as your own unbounded RE `/tmp/a/b/c.$x\.(.+?)`.

*Please clarify in your question if I have mis-interpreted the intent of your own RE and I'll readdress that here.*

```
check() {
    local file
    for file in /tmp/a/b/c."$1".?*
    do
        if [[ -f "$file" ]]
        then
            # do something
            :
        fi
    done
}
```

If you really need to use `find`, try this

```
check() {
    find /tmp/a/b -type f -name "c.$1.?*" -print0 |
        while IFS= read -r -d '' file
        do
            # do something
            :
        done
}
```

With a file `/tmp/a/b/c.1.d_e`, calling `check 1` with either suggestion will reach the `:` statement; you can verify this by replacing it with `echo "Found $file"`

Finally, since you mentioned in your question that you had been using an RE comparision to extract the last part of the match, you can also get that like this

```
# Assume $file is valid
tail="${file##*/c."$1".}"
echo "Last part of the path is $tail"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  You did't misinterpret anything.  Just that my question wasn't clear enough.  I added clarifications to my question.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried your first solution, and added `printf "checking $file\n"` right before `if` statement and it printed `checking /tmp/a/b/c.1.*?` when called `check 1`.  I was expecting `$file` should be `/tmp/a/b/c.1.d_e` as I have such file there.

Comment: @HCSF that precise example works for me. Except that you shouldn't interpolate variables into a `printf` format string. Use `printf "checking %s\n" "$file"` instead

Comment: You are right that I misused `printf`.  I fixed that.  However, I noticed that it prints `/tmp/a/b/c.1.?*` once if `/tmp/a/b/` doesn't have any file matching the pattern `/tmp/a/b/c.1.?*`.  Tho, your solution certainly works because your `if` statement tested `$file`.  Any idea why the for loop condition still meets when the folder is empty?  Thanks!

Comment: That's what globs do when there's no match. In `man bash` search for `nullglob`, as in `shopt -s nullglob`. Here though, it's of little use to us because we still need to filter out non-files such as directories